# How to click dijit.form.Button programmatically

Tags: dojo

I have form and input inside.

```
<input type="submit" label="Upload" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-attach-point="leftLogoSubmit" id="leftLogoSubmit"/>
```

Is it possible push this button programmatically?
I tried

```
this.leftLogoSubmit.onclick();
```

but it not works.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.leftLogoSubmit.onclick is not a function
```

Comment: did you try using emit.  dijit.registry.byId("leftLogoSubmit").emit('click',{})

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `on.emit()`. 
It can be done in 2 ways:

As @tik27 stated:

```
dijit.registry.byId("leftLogoSubmit").emit('click', { cancelable:true, bubbles: true})
```

Note the 2 properties on the object. Without this, the click will not work properly.

You can also do:

```
on.emit(dojo.byId("leftLogoSubmit"), 'click', { cancelable:true, bubbles: true})
```

Where `on` is required as `dojo/on`

Last but not least, you can call the `onClick` method of the button directly (like @frank proposed):

```
dijit.registry.byId("leftLogoSubmit").onClick();
```

Difference is:
- in 1st case the widget is use to access the emit method (only works with Evented widgets)
- in 2nd case `dojo/on` is used so we need to pass the button domNode instead of the widget
- in 3rd it is not a native click (so will not bubble). It just call the button click handler

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
    this.leftLogoSubmit.on("click", function() {
// Your code
});
```

Comment: it seems like click handler, but i need simply click input submit

Comment: why are you pushing the button programmatically

Comment: I need submit form, but if i do it programmatically then page refresh and paint answer, i need use this answer of current page

Answer (score 0):

you can fire the click function as.

```
this.leftLogoSubmit.onClick();
```

note: the capital C in the onClick.

Comment: it weird, seems that input was pushed but form was not submit

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do with more code? It is not clear what is your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with core JavaScript solution

```
document.getElementById("leftLogoSubmit").click();
```